How to get metadata (File Shares List) of the Storage account & configure the copy data activity for copying b/w storage accounts in the ADF?
Following my previous Q&A,
How to get the File Shares list in the metadata activity and copy all the file shares and inside data as-is to the destination storage account?
Linked Service for Source storage:

Linked Service for destination storage:

Get Metadata activity:

In the Linked Service, I have edited like below:

Error:
{
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": null,
"target": "pipeline//runid/3625b19c-e9b6-494a-a704-17acb13dda04",
"details": null,
"error": null
}

Copy Data Activity: Source:



I think you are using same dataset for get metadata activity and other activity. If you see the screenshot that you provided, it has empty value for filesharename parameter value.

If i need to provide another dataset for Metadata activity, what I need to provide in that dataset?

Are you using same dataset for both getmetadata activity and copy activity- source?

Source data set is using for get metadata activity and copy activity - source and destination data set is using in copy activity - sink.

Can u attach screenshot of copy activity with source and sink tab. This will help me to explain better

Here the 1st step - Get Metadata activity is failing - I'm unable to get the fileshares list

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The issue is because you have same dataset for both getmetadata activity and source of copy activity. You can change the dataset of get metadata activity

Click +New in the settings of get metadata activity to create new dataset.



Click azure file storage and then click binary as dataset.




Then give the linked service. Give the full file path in the linked service.


Once created new dataset, add child items as argument in the field list.
This way, you can change the dataset in metadata activity and make sure that it is different to the one on copy activity.

Sorry, could you please provide me the full pipeline from Get Metadata activity to copy activity.

There is a blog which does similar. Check the steps as given in this link.

that blog is about blob storage copy activity not about file shares. Hope the linked services, dataset creation of file share is a bit different from the blob storage object.
So, I asked the configuration of file share copy activity here. Thanks !

Did you get the output of fileshares list from the above solution given - get metadata activity?

Yes- I got. In the second step of above procedure, you need to select azure file storage linked service. I have edited the answer

Can you show me the 1st activity output please

screenshot. check the output

Apologies, we didn't understood your solution perfectly. what is the linked service configuration, dataset configuration used, get metadata activity configuration you used is not properly given in the answer. could you please rewrite your answer.

can you show me the linked service how you created for the azure file share service because it is asking me to provide a file share name manually during creation of file share service.

I had option to select it from the dropdown. If you dont have dropdown, is there any issue in giving the fileshare name manually? screenshot

Hi, there are ongoing issues with our vnet enabled storage accounts with our company policies. Once that sorted, then we will test your solution and accept the solution & come back with a new question if any doubt. It takes about a week of time. Thanks for the solution.
